# How to create GalleryShortcut when presenting UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, image-gallery

I want to give option for user to take a photo or upload one as his avatar in my app.
I believe there is no need to put two different buttons for that, so instead I would like to make the next scenario:

user clicks on "Add Picture" button and automatically UIImagePicker with source control - camera is presented.
But, I want to have shortcut for gallery in the corner, where user could click, get into gallery and search for pic he would use.

Here is the screenshot of what I need:
[image]

Part with red circle is important part.
How do I put it there?

(Initially it's not there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-build way to do this.
What you can do is to make an overlay for Camera View.
Bear in mind that you have to make different view for each device, as every device already has different positioning inside the CameraView.

One example would be this:

```
- (IBAction)addImage:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIView* overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,self.view.frame.size.height-60 , 40, 40)];

    overlay.opaque=NO;

    overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    UIButton* btnGallery = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0 , 40, 40)];

    [btnGallery setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_gallery"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    btnGallery.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];





    [overlay addSubview:btnGallery];



    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];

    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    [imagePicker.view addSubview:overlay];



    [btnGallery addTarget:self

                   action:@selector(openGallery)

         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    _picker = imagePicker;



    [self presentViewController:imagePicker

                       animated:YES

                     completion:nil];

}





-(void)openGallery

{
    UIImagePickerController *gallery =    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    gallery.delegate = self;

    gallery.sourceType =    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    gallery.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];

    gallery.allowsEditing = YES;

    _gallery = gallery;

    [_picker presentViewController:gallery

                          animated:YES

                        completion:nil];

}
```